# Arduino compare string on sd card to now.unixtime

Tags: arduino, unix-timestamp

I thought this was going to be simple but got bogged down in ascii, unsigned long, atoi etc.

I have a single unix time stamp string as the first line in a file (setup.txt) on a sd card.
I would like to compare this string to now.unix time and start logging when they match. Unsigned long to now.unixtime obviously not a problem. Sd card string to unsigned long major headache(for me).
Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Steve

Comment: You will need to add detail to this question to get an answer.  The base Arduino does not have a real time clock, so comparing time stamps seems impossible.  What is the source of time you are having a problem with?

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. I am using the ds1307 with the RTClib.h. I write a ten digit timestamp to the SD and I use the function now.unixtime() to a long variable. I am having a problem converting the ascii representation of the ten digit number on the SD into a long variable for a comparison to trigger the data logging at a specific time. Short of multiplying any array to sucsessive powers of ten with addition Im stuck ! I just have a feeling there is a simple solution to this and appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, presuming you have a text representation of a the desired time, already converted to a number stored in the file, e.g.

```
3459039345
```

You convert to long with simple but obscure call:

```
char s[20] = "3459039345";
unsigned long startAt = strtoul(s, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, this set me on the right track, I ended up usin the char array and the atol function thats in the standard c library

Comment: I am working on a power monitor/logger with all the parameters being set from the SD card tahat will also record all the data, thanks again for your time